# how to use jquery rounded plugin in liferay theme?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I have developed a theme in liferay 6.1.

- In css I have written `border-radius` property, which is not working in
  IE6-to-IE8.
- `border-radius` is a css3 property which will work on IE9+
- I want to use jquery rounded corners in my theme in order to add
  border-radius feature to IE 6+ to IE 8 versions.

I don't know where to add jquery rounded corner plugin. I  want to use rounded corner for banner in portal_normal.vm file.

Can any one help me in where I need to add this jquery plugin and how to apply `border-radius` feature in banner of the theme?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add that js in your theme's js folder and use it by script tag inside portal_normal.vm to load it

Comment: inside of _diffs or outside of _diffs? do i have to add this $('#myheader').corner(); logic inside of portal_normal.vm ?

Comment: Any changes regarding css or script is added to files under _diffs folder. Add $('#myheader').corner(); in portal_normal.vm under script tag in document ready method.

Comment: means <script>$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myheader').corner(); 
});</script>  like this in portal_normal.vm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling complex at starting after knowing and doing mistakes i felt it was very simple: i followed the below steps to achieve the above jquery rounded functionality in my theme:

1.added the below code in portal_normal.vm file in  section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="$javascript_folder/jquery_roundcorner.js"></script>
```

2.created the jquery_roundcorner.js file under _diffs/js folder

added the below code: for adding jquery round corner functionality in banner

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('#banner').corner();
});
```

3.removed the border-radius property in banner of custom.css under _diffs.